# Boto3 delete object inside directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following snippet:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="id",
    aws_secret_access_key="secret",
    region_name="us-east-1"
)

s3 = session.resource("s3")
obj = s3.Object("mybucket", "test.txt")


obj.delete()
```

It works fine if the file is on the root of the bucket, but I need to delete a file inside a directory. My file is under: `mybucket/media/private/test.txt`

Adding the path to `"mybucket"` or `"test.txt"` in the `s3.Object()` is not working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The keyname in S3 contains also the directory path, there are no real directories in buckets.
Do it like this:

```
s3 = session.resource("s3")
obj = s3.Object("mybucket", "media/private/test.txt")
obj.delete()
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a leading slash in the object key.  I think boto3 quietly removes it for you, so this may work as written, but it isn't precisely correct.

Comment: Hi I wanted to ask how to use this if we only know partial file name. ie I know only test as the file name instead of test-1xxxxx222.txt. How could I use this to delete it?

Comment: @AbilashAmarasekaran Use the startswith method (i.e. if file.startswith('test') : file.delete() ) (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith)